# Golang Web: funçao para Head

Tags: aplicação-web, golang

Boa noite,

Estou iniciando em GO, e estou com uma duvida que pode parecer simples. Estou criando um site com GO em Backend, minha duvida é tenho o index.html e o main.go criado e estão funcionando, mas no index  quero adicionar o conteudo de outro arquivo chamado head.html que tem todo o conteudo do que sera o cabeçalho do site, assim quando criar mais paginas reaproveito somente funçao do cabeçalho para replicar em todas as outras o head, alguem sabe como faço uma função para isso em Golang?

Comment: Depende, qual lib esta usando a lib nativa de HTTP? ou esta usando um framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considerando que esteja usando o [`html/template`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/), você pode uasr o `{{template "nome do template"}}` para que ele seja inserido.

Todos os "comandos", pode ser visualizados em https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/:

```
{{template "name"}}

    The template with the specified name is executed with nil data.

{{template "name" pipeline}}
    The template with the specified name is executed with dot set
    to the value of the pipeline.
```

---

Portanto, considerando que você tenha dois arquivos, poderia fazer:

> header.html

```
{{define "header"}}
<header>
    Este é o cabeçalho de {{.Fulano}}
</header>
{{end}}
```

> index.html

```
{{define "index"}}
{{template "header" .}}
<body>
    Este é o corpo de {{.Fulano}}
</body>
{{end}}
```

No Golang poderia usar:

```
package main

import (
    "html/template"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    t, err := template.ParseGlob(`path\to\*.html`)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    type Exemplo struct {
        Fulano string
    }

    if err = t.ExecuteTemplate(os.Stdout, "index", &Exemplo{Fulano: "Sicrano"}); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

}
```

Isso iria resultar em:

```
<header>
    Este é o cabeçalho de Sicrano
</header>

<body>
    Este é o corpo de Sicrano
</body>
```

---

Observe que é usado o `{{define}}` para dar nome para cada "arquivo". No segundo caso, no `index.html`, é usado o `{{template "header" .}}` e isso tem a intenção de injetar o conteúdo que foi definido usando `{{define "header"}}`.

---

Enfim, para injetar um no outro  utilize o `{{define "nome}}` e então utilize o `{{template "nome"}}` para inserir o conteúdo. No caso acima, é usado `{{template "nome" .}}` (note o `.` ao final) para que permitir o "header" ter acesso ao struct de `Exemplo` e ler o `Fulano`.

Comment: Era exatamente isso que eu estava precisando, apesar de parecer fácil não estava achando essa explicação na web, muito obrigado. Funcionou perfeitamente.